# Unable to run EXE's from network share

Tags: windows-10, file-sharing, windows-server-2019

Before i begin let me inform you that I've already gone through other threads here regarding the same issue, none of them seems to have helped, therefore creating my own.

The issue started recently, by the very least i think it started happening 3 weeks ago. we have a custom build application that is deployed on our Network share, the exe is lightweight program, nothing too heavy. The EXE can be ran manually or through our a shortcut but doesn't run either ways, a window about the same size as the app pops up and disappears immediately if you constantly double click on the exe.

All our Client computers are Windows 10 1909 build. All our servers are VMs running on a Hyper-V host and Windows Server 2019 latest version as well. only the Hyper-V Host is Server 2016 and the application runs fine on that server only. Infact all other EXEs can be opened through the network share (not on the same server but on a VM) on that 2016 host but none of the exe's open on any other client computer or VM's. The respective GPO to trust UNC paths is enabled and applied, there are no errors or warning whatsoever when launching any of the exe's, the files just don't open no matter how many times you click on it.

Any Ideas?

Comment: So it appears the program starts, then terminates. In order to find out if it crashes, look in the eventlog -> application for a mention of a crash. If not, copy the file to other places and find a way to make it work. If still not working, contact the developers so they can solve the issue, or make a change to generate a logfile to pinpoint the error.

Comment: No events related to it in the Logs, also If i copy the program folder from A:\{NETWORK Share\} to C:\ or D:\ or any other local drive it works fine. I also tried assigning full control permission to everyone.

Comment: Also we have a P:\ again a shared drive which has programs in it, one of the folders has the entire SystemInternals suite e.g. Process Monitor. when i try to run it, it doesn't open at all. but copying the directory to local C:\ then launching it works fine

Comment: Have you tried restarting the server that produced the share? sounds like a weird file lock.

Comment: yeah my first choice actually was to restart it since it used to work fine.